# How to draw rectangles from a JList Selection

Tags: java, jpanel, drawing, jlist

I'm looking for some help regarding a Java program I'm writing. I need to display a simple bar graph consisting of rectangles based off of data saved in an array that has been generated by a JList selection event. However, nothing is drawn in the JPanel and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

1. List Selection Event (For reference)

   ```
   try
   {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader((new FileReader("scores.txt")));

   String sLine;

   while ((sLine = in.readLine()) != null)
   {
       vecAthlete.addElement(new Stage3_DataFile(sLine));
   }

   String[] saAthlete = new String[vecAthlete.size()];
   for (int iI = 0; iI < vecAthlete.size(); iI++)
       saAthlete[iI] = vecAthlete.get(iI).sName;
   jList_Athlete.setListData(saAthlete);
   jList_Athlete.setSelectedIndex(0);

   // Reading input line by line
   // Close file
       in.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
       System.out.println("ERROR: Could not read text file!");
   }
   jList_Athlete.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener()
   {
       public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent e)
       {
           double[][] daRun = new double[2][7];

           final double dScoreUsed = 5;
           double dMinScoreRun1 = 10, dMaxScoreRun1 = 0;
           double dMinScoreRun2 = 10, dMaxScoreRun2 = 0;

           double dTotalRun1 = 0, dTotalRun2 = 0;

           jLabel_Athlete.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).sName);
           jLabel_Country.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).sCountry);

           jLabel_Run1_Score_1.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[0]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_2.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[1]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_3.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[2]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_4.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[3]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_5.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[4]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_6.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[5]);
       jLabel_Run1_Score_7.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun1[6]);

       jLabel_Run2_Score_1.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[0]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_2.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[1]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_3.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[2]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_4.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[3]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_5.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[4]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_6.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[5]);
       jLabel_Run2_Score_7.setText(vecAthlete.get(jList_Athlete.getSelectedIndex()).saTempRun2[6]);


       daRun[0][0] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_1.getText());
       daRun[0][1] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_2.getText());
       daRun[0][2] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_3.getText());
       daRun[0][3] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_4.getText());
       daRun[0][4] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_5.getText());
       daRun[0][5] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_6.getText());
       daRun[0][6] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run1_Score_7.getText());

       daRun[1][0] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_1.getText());
       daRun[1][1] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_2.getText());
       daRun[1][2] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_3.getText());
       daRun[1][3] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_4.getText());
       daRun[1][4] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_5.getText());
       daRun[1][5] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_6.getText());
       daRun[1][6] = Double.parseDouble(jLabel_Run2_Score_7.getText());

       for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
       {   
           if(daRun[0][i] <= dMinScoreRun1)
           {
               dMinScoreRun1 = daRun[0][i];
           }
           if(daRun[0][i] >= dMaxScoreRun1)
           {
               dMaxScoreRun1 = daRun[0][i];
           }

           dTotalRun1 += daRun[0][i];
       }

       dTotalRun1 = (dTotalRun1 - dMinScoreRun1 - dMaxScoreRun1) / dScoreUsed;
       jLabel_TotalRun1.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalRun1));
       jLabel_Run1AddInfo.setText("Min Score: " + (dMinScoreRun1) + ", Max Score: " + (dMaxScoreRun1));

       for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
       {
           if(daRun[1][i] <= dMinScoreRun2)
           {
               dMinScoreRun2 = daRun[1][i];
           }
           if(daRun[1][i] >= dMaxScoreRun2)
           {
               dMaxScoreRun2 = daRun[1][i];
           }

           dTotalRun2 += daRun[1][i];
       }

       dTotalRun2 = (dTotalRun2 - dMinScoreRun2 - dMaxScoreRun2) / dScoreUsed;
       jLabel_TotalRun2.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalRun2));
       jLabel_Run2AddInfo.setText("Min Score: " + (dMinScoreRun2) + ", Max Score: " + (dMaxScoreRun2));

       if(dTotalRun1 >= dTotalRun2)
           jLabel_FinalScore.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalRun1));  
       else
           jLabel_FinalScore.setText(String.valueOf(dTotalRun2));  


       jPanel_Graph.repaint();
   }
   });
   ```
2. JPanel Definitions

   ```
       JPanel jPanel_Graph = new JPanel();
   jPanel_Graph.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
   jPanel_Graph.setBounds(729, 159, 700, 200);
   frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel_Graph);

   img = new BufferedImage(jPanel_Graph.getWidth(),
                           jPanel_Graph.getHeight(),
                           BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

   g2dimg = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();

   // Draw a filled white coloured rectangle on the entire area to clear it.
   g2dimg.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
   g2dimg.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
   ```
3. JPanel Drawing Event

   ```
   class myJPanel extends JPanel
   {
   private Rectangle2D.Double rectangle;

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
       {
           dHeight = daRun[0][i];

           rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);
           g2dimg.setPaint(Color.red);
           g2dimg.draw(rectangle);
           g2dimg.fill(rectangle);

           dX += dXIncrement;
           g2dimg.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not really sure how that should all be pieced together or in fact, if it was, it would actually work.  How does `jPanel_Graph` know what it should paint?

Comment: Consider, the `JPanel` (which ever one it is) is responsible for rendering the model, your `ListSelectionListener` is responsible for generating that model and passing it to the `JPanel` so it can render the results

Comment: Alright, so taking that into consideration, how do I actually pass that information to the JPanel to render in said results?

Comment: `graphPane.setModel(...)` ... how else do you pass data?

Comment: Ahaha so simple, sorry I'm new to Java so my general knowledge isn't exactly great.

Answer (score 1):

So, from what I can tell, there is no way for your "graph" to know what it should paint. The basic idea is, your "graph" should be focused on painting the data/model, so you need some way to tell it when the data changes.

There are lots of ways you might do this, for example, you could devise a model, which you add/remove data to, which could trigger updates that the graph pane listeners for and then updates itself with the new data.

Or you just pass the data you want updated directly to the graph pane, which in this case, might the simplest solution available to you

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private GraphPane graphPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultListModel<Double> listmodel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
                listmodel.addElement(Math.random());
            }

            graphPane = new GraphPane();
            add(graphPane);

            JList<Double> listData = new JList<>(listmodel);
            add(new JScrollPane(listData), BorderLayout.WEST);

            listData.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    graphPane.setData(listData.getSelectedValuesList().toArray(new Double[0]));
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class GraphPane extends JPanel {

        private Double[] data;

        public void setData(Double[] data) {
            this.data = data;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                double barWidth = getWidth() / (double)data.length;
                int xPos = 0;
                for (Double value : data) {
                    double height = (getHeight() - 1) * value;
                    Rectangle2D bar = new Rectangle2D.Double(xPos, getHeight() - height, barWidth, height);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g2d.fill(bar);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.draw(bar);
                    xPos += barWidth;
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```